# PHP PEAR Call to undefined method System::tmpdir()

Tags: php, pear

I have same PHP, PEAR and ZEND Engine version on two servers. On one server everything works, on second server I download an empty .xls file. If I turn on error_reporting, then in my .xls file I have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method System::tmpdir() in 
>   /var/www/kasa/packages/OLE/PPS/File.php on line 50.

Line 50 in File.php looks:

```
$this->_tmp_dir = System::tmpdir();
```

In class System, I have method tmpdir()

```
function tmpdir() {
        if (OS_WINDOWS) {
            if ($var = isset($_ENV['TMP']) ? $_ENV['TMP'] : getenv('TMP')) {
                return $var;
            }
            if ($var = isset($_ENV['TEMP']) ? $_ENV['TEMP'] : getenv('TEMP')) {
                return $var;
            }
            if ($var = isset($_ENV['USERPROFILE']) ? $_ENV['USERPROFILE'] : getenv('USERPROFILE')) {
                return $var;
            }
            if ($var = isset($_ENV['windir']) ? $_ENV['windir'] : getenv('windir')) {
                return $var;
            }
            return getenv('SystemRoot') . '\temp';
        }
        if ($var = isset($_ENV['TMPDIR']) ? $_ENV['TMPDIR'] : getenv('TMPDIR')) {
            return $var;
        }
        return realpath('/tmp');
    }
```

Why on one server is everything ok nd on another I have error?

Comment: Silly question but are you sure you don't have more than one System class. Also, you should specify this method as `public` and `static`. - **Edit** Sorry that was a messy comment

Comment: Additionally, are you sure the file with the System class has been included/required? I would expect the error message to be different but worth checking if nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have more than one System class and your include_paths are different on each server - one where PEAR's System.php is detected first, and everything is working ok, and the other where it is not.

You should compare these, by even just doing "echo get_include_path();"
 and seeing what differences you spot.